# Group by rows order by min price first

Tags: mysql

I have a table 'terms':

```
([id], [t_id], [d_start], [d_end], [price], [departure_from])
```

with values:

```
(12,10, 2018-5-5, 2018-5-15, 95, london),  
(11,10, 2018-5-5, 2018-5-15, 60, london),  
(10,10, 2018-5-5, 2018-5-15, 90, london),  
( 9, 10, 2018-5-5, 2018-5-15, 90, prag),  
( 8, 10, 2018-5-5, 2018-5-15, 85, prag),   
( 7, 10, 2018-5-5, 2018-5-15, 70, prag),   
( 6, 10, 2018-6-8, 2018-6-18, 30, london),    
( 5, 10, 2018-6-8, 2018-6-18, 20, london),   
( 4, 10, 2018-6-8, 2018-6-18, 90, london),   
( 3, 10, 2018-6-8, 2018-6-18, 90, prag),  
( 2, 10, 2018-6-8, 2018-6-18, 10, prag),   
( 1, 10, 2018-6-8, 2018-6-18, 70, prag);
```

and  I want to group by d_start,d_end,departure_from with order by price and I want to order by price first.
I have query:

```
(SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM terms 
   WHERE t_id=10 ORDER BY price) t
GROUP BY d_start,d_end,departure_from ORDER BY d_start)
```

Result I want:  4 rows with min price :
(11,10, 2018-5-5, 2018-5-15, 60, london),
( 7, 10, 2018-5-5, 2018-5-15, 70, prag),
( 5, 10, 2018-6-8, 2018-6-18, 20, london),
( 2, 10, 2018-6-8, 2018-6-18, 10, prag),

My first question there. Thank you for any help.

I found result that work for me:
(SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM terms 
   WHERE t_id=10 GROUP BY d_start,d_end,departure_from,price ORDER BY d_start) t
GROUP BY d_start,d_end,departure_from)

What do you think? It's OK?

Comment: Using `SELECT * ... GROUP BY start,end,from` is asking for invalid data.. https://www.psce.com/en/blog/2012/05/15/mysql-mistakes-do-you-use-group-by-correctly/

Comment: Please format your question

Comment: "but is not giving expected result." Also post the expected results.

Comment: For the table you have column name 'from'; its mysql reserved keyword; should not have it in column name; change to some other name

Comment: Please add expected result in your question

Comment: `start` and `end` are also  mysql reserved keywords @ManiMuthuPandi

Comment: Why do you want to use GROUP BY when you don't use aggregate functions?

Comment: `select t2.t_id,t2.d_start,t2.d_end,max(t2.price),t2.departure_from
        from terms t2 where t2.t_id = 10
        group by t2.t_id,t2.d_start,t2.d_end,t2.departure_from` will do

Answer (score 0):

With the information you gave, the main problem you have is the variable names. Just add an `` for every of them.

Like:

`` SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM terms 
   WHERE t_id=10 ORDER BY price) 
GROUP BY `start`,`end`,`from` ORDER BY start ``

Answer (score 0):

You need to use correlated subquery for this...

```
select t.*
from terms t
where t.price = (
    select min(t2.price)
    from terms t2
    where t2.d_start = t.d_start
        and t2.d_end = t.d_end
        and t2.departure_from = t.departure_from
)
order by t.d_start;
```

Comment: `4 rows with min price` isn't that condition satisfied ?

Comment: I try but it is very slowly and I don't have result. Maybe I don't know how must by writen query corectly.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94d5cf/2, please check this and add some more data to test.

Comment: When is small table, works, but I have around 20000 rows and after 1 minute browser stops without result. It's so difficult?